# Route model binding in Laravel 5.6

Tags: eloquent, routes, laravel-5.6

I am using Laravel resource controller with route model binding in my API development project. I have below code

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
    return $post->comments()->get();

}
```

I am using below URL

http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/1

I would like to retrieve both `post` values with `comments` value.

But I am getting only `comments` values.

Comment: did you create a relationship between post and comment an both models ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Eloquent `load` aka Lazy Eager Loading https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

> Sometimes you may need to eager load a relationship after the parent model has already been retrieved. For example, this may be useful if you need to dynamically decide whether to load related models:

In your case would be something like

`$post->load('comments')`

Comment: Thanks @Vaidas. One comment has one images. 

I have relationship comment model is like below

`public function image()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Model\image', 'id', 'image_id');
}`

How can I attach image with this Query ?

Answer (score 1):

You should have your relationship in your models "Post", "Comment" and get of the next shape.

```
$post->comments;
```

If you don't have the relationship in your models you should post your models in this answer pls.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.One comment has one images. 

I have relationship comment model is like below

`public function image()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Model\image', 'id', 'image_id');
}`

How can I attach image with this Query ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the relationships set in both models, just sending the post will load the post and the comments